# ¿Cómo convertir valores determinados valores numéricos a valores NA de manera eficiente en R?

Tags: r, condiciones, dataframe

Tengo 2 dataframes sobre 2 encuestas (Encuesta Nacional de Salud de los hogares y de los adultos), en los cuales, muchas de las variables dan como opción de respuesta "No sabe/No contesta", asignándoles un número o un par de números a dicha respuesta.

Esta respuesta (NS/NC):

- en la mayoría de ocasiones/variables/pregunta se les asigna los números 8 y 9 para indicar si "no sabe" o "no contesta", respectivamente.
- En una variable corresponde solo al 8, ya que solo da la opción de indicar "no sabe". Análogamente para el 9.
- En otra variable son el 98 y el 99
- en otras el 998 y el 999
- Hay otras variables que utilizan estos valores (8,9,998...) para indicar otras opciones que no corresponde a "no sabe" o "no contesta".

Entonces lo que deseo es convertir todos estos NS/NC en valores NA para posteriormente tratarlos de manera más cómoda con el resto de valores missing. Lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

```
# Variables de la Encuesta Adultos con respuesta de NS/NC
vars_na_89_A <- c("enf_cron","SM_estres","tipo_act_fis","frec_act_fis","fuma")

vars_na_8_A <- c("sit_lab")
vars_na_9_A <- c("clase_pr")
vars_na_9899_A <- c("niv_est")
vars_na_998999_A <- c("altura","peso")

# Variables de la Encuesta Hogares con respuesta de NS/NC
vars_na_89_H <- c("ruido","malos","agua","limpieza", "cont_indus","cont_otras",
                  "escasez_verde","molest_animal" ,"delincuencia")
vars_na_9899_H <- c("n_dormitorios", "ingreso")
vars_na_998999_H <-c("m2")

ifelse(datos_adultos[vars_na_89_A]!=8 | datos_adultos[vars_na_89_A!=9],datos_adultos,NA)
ifelse(datos_adultos[vars_na_8_A]!=8,datos_adultos,NA)
.
.
.
```

De esta manera tengo que crear un ifelse para cada tipo de NS/NC de cada una de las dos encuestas. Mi pregunta es: **¿Cómo puedo obtener el mismo resultado pero sin tantas líneas de código?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es una prueba de concepto de una forma posible de reducir un poco de código, aunque no creo que ganes mucho. La idea es definir una lista de reemplazos, donde indicas las columnas y los valores que quieres reemplazar por `NA`. Suponiendo un `data.frame` como esto:

```
set.seed(2020)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:9,98,99,998,999), 100, replace = TRUE), ncol=10))
df

    V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6 V7  V8  V9 V10
1  998   1   2   4 999 999  9 999  98  98
2  998 999 999   5 998   9  3   2   1   1
3    7   8   8   4   8 999  8   5   6 998
4    6   8   8 998 999  99  2   6   9   1
5    8  98   4  99 999   9  1   4 998   1
6    1   2   2   6   2   5  6   3   6   8
7    1   6 998   2 999  99  7   7   8 998
8    4 999   7  98   1  98  8   4   7  98
9   98   2   4   6   6   6  5   4  98   2
10   6   3   2  99   3   2  8   2  98 999
```

Y una lista de reemplazo, dónde definimos distintos criterios:

```
lista_reemplazo <- list(
  list(cols=c("V1", "V2"), na_vals=c(9,8)),
  list(cols=c("V3"), na_vals=c(998)),
  list(cols=c("V4", "V5", "V6"), na_vals=c(998, 999)),
  list(cols=c("V7", "V8"), na_vals=c(9)),
  list(cols=c("V9", "V10"), na_vals=c(8, 9, 998, 999))
)
```

Por ejemplo, el primer criterio es que en `V1` y `V2` los valores 8 y 9 sean reemplazados por `NA`, lo siguiente es iterar para procesar cada criterio:

```
for (reemplazo in lista_reemplazo) {
  for (col in reemplazo$cols) {
    df[df[, col] %in% reemplazo$na_vals, col] <- NA
  }
}

df

    V1  V2  V3 V4 V5 V6 V7  V8 V9 V10
1  998   1   2  4 NA NA NA 999 98  98
2  998 999 999  5 NA  9  3   2  1   1
3    7  NA   8  4  8 NA  8   5  6  NA
4    6  NA   8 NA NA 99  2   6 NA   1
5   NA  98   4 99 NA  9  1   4 NA   1
6    1   2   2  6  2  5  6   3  6  NA
7    1   6  NA  2 NA 99  7   7 NA  NA
8    4 999   7 98  1 98  8   4  7  98
9   98   2   4  6  6  6  5   4 98   2
10   6   3   2 99  3  2  8   2 98  NA
```

Comment: Como tengo 2 dataframes que uno posteriormente, realizaré el bucle con cada uno de ellos. Además, de la manera en que está hecho en mi pregunta no obtengo el resultado que deseo y tarda 2 minutos aproximadamente en ejecutarse por completo.

Answer (score 1):

Es difícil darte una respuesta general, ya que no se cuales son todas las columnas totales que contiene tu df, por lo que no puedo darte un ejemplo re-producible con tus datos, te recomiendo el siguiente código el cual solo funciona si sabes exactamente cuales son las columnas que contienen NA en base a los patrones que mencionas asumiendo que las columnas:
 vars_na_89_A,vars_na_8_A,vars_na_9_A,vars_na_9899_A,vars_na_998999_A,vars_na_89_H,vars_na_9899_H

no tenga un significado distinto las claves 89, 8 , 9 ,9899,998999,,89,9899, ejemplo que para vars_na_8_A 9 tenga un significado diferente a "NA"

```
library(map) #De esta libraría utilizaremos la función purrr que es muy similar apply
library(dplyr) 
library(stringr) # esta librería utilizaremos str_detect para identificar si la 
                 # columna tiene los patrones que deseamos

   df_modificar<-df %>% 
          select(vars_na_89_A,vars_na_8_A,vars_na_9_A,vars_na_9899_A,vars_na_998999_A,
              vars_na_89_H,vars_na_9899_H)
#No agrego la columna vars_na_m2_H por que no se si m2 quiere decir NA
#Para cambiarlo sobre todas las columnas y no realizarlo todo en una sola linea
#utilizo purrr

#Patrones que queremos modificar
 patrones<-paste(c(8,9,98,99,998,999),collapse = '|')
#Lo que vamos realizar es buscar los patrones sobre todas las columnas
 df_limpio<-map_df(df_modificar,function(x) ifelse(str_detect(x,pattern= 
                   patrones),"NA",x))
```

Comment: Al intentar llevar a cabo tu propuesta, el dataframe `df_limpio` solo contiene 20 variables, pero los dataframes que contienen todas las variables tienen más de 50. Desconozco por qué sucede esto, pero puedes reproducir mi problema si accedes a este enlace: (https://github.com/Perfydio/Proyecto-ENS) y accedes al archivo `script.R`. Dentro de ese script lo encontrarás entre las líneas 111 y 130 del código. Son bastantes datos y tarda bastante en cargarlos.

Comment: revisando el código veo lo siguiente, ` select(vars_na_89_A,vars_na_8_A,vars_na_9_A,vars_na_9899_A,vars_na_998999_A)` aqui falta seleccionar las columnas que terminan con H, y la columna vars_na_m2_H,el cual debería quedar asi,` select(vars_na_89_A,vars_na_8_A,vars_na_9_A,vars_na_9899_A,vars_na_998999_A,
              vars_na_89_H,vars_na_9899_H,vars_na_m2_H )`, mi duda solo seria como identificas que "m2" es "NA"

Comment: He cambiado el nombre de la variable `vars_na_m2` por `vars_na 998999_H` en la pregunta y en mi repositorio próximamente para que así se pueda identificar sus `NA` por el propio nombre, ciertamente generaba confusión.